# Passing in variable template inputs for render_template() (Flask)

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask to create a data analytics application essentially. Part of creating this application is to be able to control the number of graphs they can view per page. This involves me to pass in a changing number of template inputs when I render the HTML page. One time there might only be one input variable for one graph and the next, there could be four. How could I do this without hard coding it in?

In addition to what I should do on the python side, how would I configure my HTML template to accept a variable amount of inputs?

EDIT: So I tried the idea of passing in lists. The two lists I passed in were a list of html components and text components. Below is my code. It is not working, for some reason the javascript function I wrote literally gets printed up when I run this. I am using plotly to generate graphs, it will simply give back a bunch of HTML that you can stick in, and I used to have to do Markup("the html i got given by plotly) but now the graphs are displaying the phrase "Markup(" is getting printed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GE Data Analytics</title>
    <link rel = "shortcut icon" type="image/png" href = "/static/general_electric.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/analytics_page.css">
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id = "header">
<div id = "title">
    <img src= "/static/GE_Logo.jpg" width="50px" height = "50px">
</div>
<div id = "titlename">
    <h1>GE Digital Mammography QC Data Analytics</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div id = "divider">
    <hr class="gradient_line"></hr>
</div>

<div id="graph">
</div>

<p></p>

<p><b> Analysis: </b> </p>
<div id = "analysis">
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function createDashboard(){
        alert("{{div|safe}}");
        alert("{{content}}");
        alert("stuff seems okay");
        graphs = "{{div|safe}}";
        summaries = "{{content}}";
        alert(graphs.length);
        alert(summaries.length);
        graph = document.getElementById('graph');
        summary = document.getElementById('analysis');
        for(var i = 0; i < graphs.length;i++){
            var div1 = document.createElement('div');
            div1.setAttribute("id","new-div");
            div1.innerHTML = graphs[i];
            graph.appendChild(div1);
            for (line in summaries[i]){
                var para = document.createElement('p');
                var node = document.createTextNode(summaries[i]);
                para.appendChild(node);
                summary.appendChild(para);
            }
        }
    }
     window.onload = function(){
        createDashboard();
    };

</script>
</html>
```

python render:

```
return render_template('analytics_page.html', div=html_list, content=summary_list)
```

What the application looks like: [image]

Comment: You can use the python code in the html according to the specification of the templating engine you are using. I was replying to your second question , like if you use a templating engine you can use python code in it like `{{ if case : print('hello')}}`

Comment: One thing you could do is pass a list and iterate it over in your template.

Comment: Ah, yes,, I currently do that. I will pass in some variable on the python side: div_var for example. And then on my template, I will have {{ div_var}}. What I was asking is what do I do when I want to pass in any where from 0-4 variables? I am unsure how to configure that on both the python and the HTML side.

Comment: Oh, that could work..

Comment: Write the code and if that works out please add that as an answer or if it doesn't post it above and we will work it out .

Comment: something like `render_template("index.html", **other_args)` where `other_args` is a dictionary where all the necessary variables are put in (you should know server-side how many to put in, right?) This leverages `**kwargs` that are used in the `render_template` function.

Comment: @0decimal0 , well, I tried out the list idea and it is not going very well. I updated the question in case you wanted to see what the problem is like now.

Comment: Need an explanation `alert("{{div|safe}}");` why are you using `|` here and what is `safe`? And try not using variable name same as the `html` tag at least for the sake of readability . By the way your app page is unreadable to me not to mention I don't know what it is about .

Comment: @0decimal0, it is a flask filter that says the input is safe html.

Comment: @Julia Ok yeah got it! Not very familiar with jinja2 . By the way , I guess then it must be your problem of `html_list` , how it is created and what values it has